# Change date in Dataframe when midnight reached

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a Dataframe with a column 'Date_and_time' which is in datetime format. Unfortunately, when midnight is reached (line 15235: 2020-08-02 00:00:00.000000), the date doesn't change accordingly. So, 2020-08-02 00:00:00.000000 should go to 2020-08-03 00:00:00.00000 when midnight (00:00:00.000000) is reached. On line 15235 midnight is reached, but the date doesn't change until line 16000. How can I change this so the date is correct when midnight is reached? Thank you.

```
#Load file
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";", names=["Date", "Time", "ID1","ID2","ID3","MP","ET"], skiprows = 1 ,float_precision='round_trip')
df1 = df['Time'].str.split(expand=True)

#Use columns 'Date' and 'Time' to create column 'Date_and_time' in datetime format
df['Date_and_time'] =  (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) +
               pd.to_timedelta(df1[0]) + 
               pd.to_timedelta(df1[1].str.replace('ms','').astype(int), unit='us'))

Out[45]: 
              Date  ...              Date_and_time
0       2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 21:21:46.000000
1       2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 21:21:46.082191
2       2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 21:21:46.164383
3       2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 21:21:46.246575
4       2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 21:21:46.328767
           ...  ...                        ...
15235   2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 00:00:00.000000
15236   2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 00:00:00.082191
15237   2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 00:00:00.164383
15238   2020/08/02  ... 2020-08-02 00:00:00.246575
           ...  ...                        ...
16000   2020/08/03  ... 2020-08-03 00:00:16.082191
           ...  ...                        ...
330404  2020/08/03  ... 2020-08-03 03:00:33.000000
330405  2020/08/03  ... 2020-08-03 03:00:33.040513
330406  2020/08/03  ... 2020-08-03 03:00:33.081026
330407  2020/08/03  ... 2020-08-03 03:00:33.121539
330408  2020/08/03  ... 2020-08-03 03:00:33.162052

[330409 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: How are `Date` and `Date_and_time` produced? What do you mean by "when midnight is reached"

Comment: Pandas is having the option to extract the date from the datetime format. which means whatever the date is there in the input timestamp, It will extract the date. So here we need to do some modification in the input data itself. based on the time need to adjust the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially another question requiring the "diff-cumsum" trick to accumulate the number of negative changes. In this case, however, `.diff()` does not support datetime difference so it would be more tricky to do.

Here is a quick and dirty showcase on `df["Date_and_time"]`. You should do the similar on the other columns involved by yourself.

```
from datetime import timedelta

#df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"\s{2,}")
df["Date_and_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_and_time"])
# get timestamp in nanoseconds
df["ns"] = df["Date_and_time"].values.astype(np.int64)
# detect reversed time change and accumulate days
df["days"] = (df["ns"].diff() < 0).cumsum()
# add the days found 
df["Date_and_time_new"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["Date_and_time"] + timedelta(days=row["days"]), axis=1)

df
Out[76]: 
          Date              Date_and_time  ...  days          Date_and_time_new
0   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 21:21:46.000000  ...     0 2020-08-02 21:21:46.000000
1   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 21:21:46.082191  ...     0 2020-08-02 21:21:46.082191
2   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 21:21:46.164383  ...     0 2020-08-02 21:21:46.164383
3   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 21:21:46.246575  ...     0 2020-08-02 21:21:46.246575
4   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 21:21:46.328767  ...     0 2020-08-02 21:21:46.328767
5   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 00:00:00.000000  ...     1 2020-08-03 00:00:00.000000
6   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 00:00:00.082191  ...     1 2020-08-03 00:00:00.082191
7   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 00:00:00.164383  ...     1 2020-08-03 00:00:00.164383
8   2020/08/02 2020-08-02 00:00:00.246575  ...     1 2020-08-03 00:00:00.246575
9   2020/08/03 2020-08-03 00:00:16.082191  ...     1 2020-08-04 00:00:16.082191
10  2020/08/03 2020-08-03 03:00:33.000000  ...     1 2020-08-04 03:00:33.000000
11  2020/08/03 2020-08-03 03:00:33.040513  ...     1 2020-08-04 03:00:33.040513
12  2020/08/03 2020-08-03 03:00:33.081026  ...     1 2020-08-04 03:00:33.081026
13  2020/08/03 2020-08-03 03:00:33.121539  ...     1 2020-08-04 03:00:33.121539
14  2020/08/03 2020-08-03 03:00:33.162052  ...     1 2020-08-04 03:00:33.162052
[15 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: It's just the built-in timedelta object. `from datetime import timedelta`.

Comment: This is great, can this be changed to 4am instead of midnight? Thanks.